# Making 2 images move, similiar to "marquee" style

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

I'm trying to figure out a CSS or jQuery style code that will function similarly to the `<marquee>` HTML element. Essentially I'm trying to get 2 images on a picture, that slide up-and-down approx. 10-15 pixels, slowly. When one is clicked, it will stop the other image, dim the screen, and an additional pop-up will come with a "Bio" of the picture clicked.

I have managed the jQuery/CSS to get the screen dim, and the window pop-up (I think I may have made that WAY more complicated than intended), but I feel like using an HTML `marquee` is very dated. I've looked all over, but having an issue finding code that does what I am requesting. No key clicks, or mouse overs involved. (I'm not sure how to use .animate and make it automatically run. Still learning jQuery.

I know `.animate(on.click)` [Wrong syntax, I know] but I'm not sure how `.animate` just period works. I mean z.animate(function(){z etc might work - but would it stop when my image is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) on MDN.

CSS transitions dictate the behavior of the animation and `animation` can allow it to last indefinitely until it's clicked. Since it can be assigned to a CSS class, that should allow it to be toggle-able like you want, so to make it stop, just remove the CSS class it's defined in from the image.

Comment: @empiric It's hard to give more specific advice without any groundwork. OP hasn't even provided HTML, I'd need at least that to give a more complete answer.

Comment: So I made a basic code - https://jsfiddle.net/3RWXB/67/ I'm having two issues. A) My Marquee is having a seizure and I have no idea why. B) When you click Test Image to bring the front-box/dim the back; How would I get the marquee to stop? I could do a "onClick.findelementID" etc, but the issue is, you can close the box WITHOUT hitting a specific button.

So how would it know to resume?

Also I still feel like marquee is very dated and I should be doing something else.